# Python - hide / minimalize subprocess window

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, subprocess

I'am working on linux project, involving python to launch new subprocess instances (up to 8).
These subprocesses are GUI apps (currently running on gnome, but it's open) and normally they will start in full screen mode. Moreover, these subprocesses have always only one main window.

Now, my python app has to manage these subprocesses (let's call them windows) a little.
What i need to achieve is to:

1. Terminate the app (done),
2. Send a keystroke (i know how to
   do this, however i don't know how to send Windows key combinations),
3. Hide OR minimalize a window so, that it's not accessible to a
   user.

The last thing is (while i am not familiar to linux gui programming) hardest and most crucial (to the project) thing. The best would be to being able to hide the window and then show it when i need it. Alternatively, i could just minimalize it, because my app is going to be also in full screen, so i just have somehow to prevent windows from switching.

I started with subprocess python lib and popen class. Seems to be enough for 1-2. Any guides would be lovely!

Altenatively, i also came up with following idea - instead of hiding or minimalizing, sending a window to other, secured (preventing user access) desktop. I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `xpybutil` library which interfaces Window Manager functions like you asked about (minimize, find, even strip window decoration, etc).

You can try it [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xpybutil).

Comment: I also found out, that i can use wmctrl to hide the window. Quick test prove it's working. Thanks, i believe this solves my problem!